# Some problems with creating flutter projects with commands，please help thanks

Tags: flutter

After using the command to create a flutter project, why can't a directory be created in the lib directory? At present, it seems that only a package can be created, as shown in the figure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its default sturcture. your main folder is lib folder where you can add dart files.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the project structure setting - is there flutter path is set or not..if not then provide the path..

Make sure you install Flutter & dart plugin in the android studio...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Install flutter and dart first.
Set up environmentals path for flutter. [Link for adding path](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

[**Fore More**](https://medium.com/codechai/flutter-installation-setup-with-android-studio-326dea65f609)